I have a 2014 qx60, ive replaced all plugs and one bad coil and air filter but i still have rough idle and no drivablilty because the engine shutters
I have replaced all plugs and the bad coil and cleaned the mass airflow sensor, why does it still sound like a Subaru at idle  and shake and jitter while driving with traffic unless using the manual tap shift? I need help bad.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What codes are present? If you've replaced plugs/coil and you're still getting the same thing, more than likely it's a fueling problem.
